# Cos'è un "mezzo fiasco" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Una volta ci spingemmo fino alla Mostra d’Oltremare con due mie compagne di scuola, che però s’intimidirono quando seppero che era sposata da più di un anno, e si comportarono come se le avessi obbligate a uscire con mia madre, rispettose, compassate. Una le chiese incerta: 
>         «Hai un bambino?».  
>         Lila fece cenno di no.  
>         «Non vengono?». 
>         Lei fece cenno di no.  
>         La serata da quel momento fu **un mezzo fiasco**.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiasco/) ho trovato che "fiasco" ha il senso figurato di "grosso insuccesso", ma non sono sicura di cosa significhi "un mezzo fiasco". Un "mezzo insuccesso"?

Comment: Sì, *un mezzo fiasco* si usa in riferimento a qualcosa (una festa, un evento etc.) che non è riuscito proprio come ci si aspettava. Una delusione.

Comment: @Josh61: Quindi, la differenza tra "fiasco" e "mezzo fiasco" è che un "fiasco" è un "grosso insuccesso", mentre invece un "mezzo fiasco" è un "insuccesso non tanto grosso"?

Comment: Sì, di solito si usa quando va male qualcosa ma l'evento o la festa non sono del tutto compromessi. O quando le attese sono alte ma non vengono rispettate del tutto.

Comment: Se guardi qui, tra i mezzi fiaschi di vino, trovi esempi nel senso figurato. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+un+mezzo+fiasco&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20mezzo%20fiasco%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Posso traddure "mezzo fiasco" in inglese come "semi-fiasco"?

Comment: @Steve - "partial failure" è probabilmente un'espressione più chiara: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/F/fiasco.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Risposta da Josh61 nei commenti

> Sì, un mezzo fiasco si usa in riferimento a qualcosa (una festa, un evento etc.) che non è riuscito proprio come ci si aspettava. Una delusione. [...] Di solito si usa quando va male qualcosa ma l'evento o la festa non sono del tutto compromessi. O quando le attese sono alte ma non vengono rispettate del tutto.
>
> Se guardi [qui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20un%20mezzo%20fiasco&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20mezzo%20fiasco%3B%2Cc0), tra i mezzi fiaschi di vino, trovi esempi nel senso figurato.